# sql statement to make database should not contain more than 20 distinct phone numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my sqlite database, there are 3 colomns. 1.id(primary key), 2.name, 3.phonenumber. There is a chance that more than one row can have the same phone number. I need to maintain the database in such a way that the database should not contain more than 20 distinct phone numbers. That is if there multiple rows with same phone number, all those rows would be counted as one. which sql statement I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Before you insert a number, check the current count:

```
select  count(distinct PhoneNumber)
from    YourTable
```

If the count is 20, do not insert the new number.

If your application is concurrent and different threads or processes can write at the same time, you should check both before and after the insert.

Comment: i dont't want stop insertion. I want to delete from the begining when I call the function to delete.

Comment: You want to think about this some more.  From your comment, you might delete a valid record due to a subsequent typo.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want your database to do if, when inserting a new row, it finds a row with the telephone number already existing. Do you want it to overwrite the name (in which case you'll need an UPDATE), or ignore the new data?